# If f is increasing, then show that g is also increasing

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, improper-integrals

[image]

I know that in order for g to be increasing, its derivative must be positive. But, I have a hard time showing that its derivative is indeed positive.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you find the derivative?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.

Comment: What I meant was, do you know how to find the derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

By the Fundamental theorem of Calculus
$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{x}f(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}f(x)-f(t)dt.$$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have and I was also able to prove that it is positive for (0,∞). Thanks anyways! :)